# Without touching web.xml adding web application 404 error page at run time

Tags: java

I have an application which is owned by third party. I have the source code for the application but not allowed to change it.

My only option is to configure its spring.xml files or add modules and java files.
Is there any way to add a error page for say 404 error for complete application.

My only restriction is to not to modify the web.xml file. I can modify or add Java code.

Comment: Like the first comment, I fail to see a way, except maybe if you have an Apache (or another server but Apache is common with Java) as reverse proxy in front of your application server. Then you could configure the error pages on the Apache itself.

Comment: Thanks, at present we have this approach in place but the problem is that its difficult to control the changes to apache http and sometime other teams override our changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best approach, but at least this is possible - add a filter to your application that intercepts all of the responses. If you're able to verify which response from the server indicates what you need, you can send whatever to the client.

Comment: Don't you need to declare this in the web.xml? If this is possible through the Spring configuration, maybe you could link some documentation or add a code sample?

Comment: You don't if you use a Servlet 3.0 server. There you can use the [@WebFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html) annotation.

Comment: Thanks, This will solve my problem but inside filter how will i check for error code and redirect to error page?

Comment: Inside the filter you can work with the response object - read the response code and if it is the one you expect (e.g. 404), you can directly replace the current response body with your error page.